# Collision stops working when colliding with two other colliders at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The player is a wheel with a `Circle Collider 2d` which can jump and move when it collides with the ground (`isGrounded` variable).

I have another two `gameObjets` with `Polygon Colliders 2d` that represent the ground and are connected side by side.

The player works perfectly, however when it collides with both ground at the same time the collision no longer works even though the player is still standing on one of the grounds. 
The variable `isGrounded` becomes false and lose control of the player which will not move or jump.

I am using Unity3d 4.5

```
public class Wheel : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision){
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground"){
        Global.IS_PLAYER_GROUNDED = false;
        //Debug.Log("exit");
        }
    }   

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground"){
            Global.IS_PLAYER_GROUNDED = true;
            //Debug.Log("enter");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey can you try to add OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll)
{//add exactly what's written in oncollisionenter 
}
 I am guessing this should help not that sure though if it doesn't ill try and think of another way for you

Comment: Thanks @Aodai...Finally I understood what OnCollisionStay2D could be useful for.